Debezium signalling custom channel doesn't work
We are using Debezium connector for mysql version 2.4.2
We implemented a custom signal channel in Java which consume the signal messages from a Kafka topic,
However we are unable to get it to work.
We copied the jar to the debezium connector directory (we also tried copy the jar to the same directory where the custom converter jar is located) and added "signal.enabled.channels" config (with the name we gave to the reader as a value) to the connector configuration as explained here:
https://debezium.io/blog/2023/07/10/custom-http-signaling-notification/
In order to check it we added logs to the init method and to the reader constructor but we are not seeing those logs or any sign that the snapshot was executed after we produced a proper signal message to the topic.
What are we missing?
Thanks for assisting,
Sefi
Dev tech lead
SKAI
